# Migration from SQLCipher V1 to Room DB V2 on App Update:

Tags: java, kotlin, android-room, database-migration, sqlite-cipher

I build two apps with the same package name:

1. In the first app, I use SQLCipher using "Pass_Phrase" (Version_1 DB) for CRUD operations using `Java`.
2. In the second app, I just wanted to migrate from SQLCipher to Room (Version_2 DB) and also read data from SQLCipher and put it into Room DB using `Kotlin`.

I completed the first app and was stuck at migration's step in the second app. Need your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2. you could use a Migration, this has the Room database passed to it as a [SupportSQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase)

So you could then either

- **open** the original (encrypted) database and then access it as you would (have done), perhaps unloading the data into Cursors for loading into the Room version, or
- **`ATTACH`** the original database to the Room database (via the `SupportSQLiteDatabase`'s [`execSQL` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String))), and then copy the data using SQL and finally **`DETACH`** the original database.

When a database is attached, then it's components, such as tables, are available (you should use the given schema_name to distinguish components with the same name). See [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)

- Note the ATTACH SQL would be along the lines of `ATTACH 'the_path_to_the_database' AS 'the_schema_name_to_use' KEY 'the_key'`

  - ***`the_path_to_the_database`*** being the path to the database to be attached
  - ***`the_schema_name_to_use`*** can be an arbitrary value with some limitations (not main or temp).
  - ***`the_key`*** being the secret key

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026198/in-the-documentation-says-we-should-use-singleton-for-roomdatabase-instance-is/73028909#73028909) includes an example that uses the first method (as per the MainDatabase class, albeit in Java *(which should take little effort to convert to Kotlin)*)